# Run macro when user tabs off or presses enter in a specific Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple spreadsheet, that looks like this

```
         A            B            C
 1       ID           Name         Type
 2       124T
```

Row 1, with the column names is always going to be fixed. Column names will never change.

User will come in and enter a value in Cell A2 and what I'm trying to do is, run a Macro behind the doors once user either Tabs Off or Presses Enter in cell A2.

What my goal is, is when User leave cell A2, I want to run a macro to validate if the ID is actually correct. If it is, I will change the color of font.

EDIT:
The macro establishes an ADODB connection to a SQL Server DB where I validate if the value in Cell A2 is in fact valid. If it is valid, I want to change the font to green, if it is not valid, I change the color font to red.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Does [data validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) fullfill your needs? Otherwise check out the [Worksheet.SelectionChange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use a `Worksheet_Change` event.

To manage the scope of the macro, limit the range of interest to `Column A` and make sure that only one cell is being modified at a time. If multiple cells can change at once (*possibly from pasting a range of IDs all at once*) you will need  to modify the macro to loop through the `Target` range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
    
        'ADODB SQL server Connection Code
        'ID Validation Code

        'You can change font color of changed (Target) cell a few ways
            'Target.Font.Color = vbRed
            'Target.Font.Color = RGB( #, #, #)
            'Target.Font.ColorIndex = ...
    
    
    End If

End Sub
```

---

If your macro is making any value changes then you will also want to temporarily disable events with `Application.EnableEvents = False` before doing so to help both limit scope & avoid the infinite loop & resultant crash.

Comment: Good callout @BigBen as usual :)

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you

Comment: Since I can enter values in any cell in Column A, how can I reference the specific Cell that initiates the Macro. Say I enter value in A3, I need to capture that value and pass it to my SQL query, but I'm not sure how to dynamically do that

Comment: The variable `Target` refers to the cell that has been changed. So, `Target.Value` is the ID that was just entered. Every time you see `Target` in the macro it is referring to the changed cell. Notice that is the object you want to modify so it should follow it's the object you also want to validate

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot